# Simple CSS3 Animation not working in Webkit

Tags: css, animation, webkit

Building out a site here: http://chooseavirb.com/strat/

For some reason webkit - chrome, safari -animations aren't firing:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideright{
0% {transform: translate(0px, 0px)}
20% {transform: translate(00px,0px)}
25% {transform: translate(150px, 0px)}
45% {transform: translate(150px,0px)}
50% {transform: translate(300px,0px)}
70% {transform: translate(300px,0px)}
75% {transform: translate(150px,0px)}
95% {transform: translate(150px,0px)}
100% {transform: translate(0px,0px)}
}

#SliderNine img
{display: inline-block;
 animation: slideright 30s infinite;
-moz-animation: slideright 30s infinite;
-webkit-animation: slideright 30s infinite;   
-ms-animation: slideright 30s infinite;     
}
```

Can anyone with expertise say whi\y this might be happening? it works fine on firefox.-

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following link.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Also use specific browser related transform animation as follows

Example:-

```
-webkit-transform:  translate(0px, 0px);

-o-transform: translate(0px, 0px); 

-moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
```

it may create Magic for U..!

This may help as example

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: I think we looked at this already, Ameya. Sorry, it didn't help. Unless we overlooked something.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Please check this link, it helped me.